# Processing player flicker on multiplayer

Tags: java, server, processing

I have made a small multiplayer game to learn the aspects of multiplayer server/client. When one player is connected everything will work as expected. However when a second clients connects then the two players will begin to flicker. When the players are moved on top of each other the flickering will stop. I have condensed the original code into a small example that will still reproduce the problem. Any explanation or idea as to why this is happening will be greatly appreciated!

Here is the server code:

```
import processing.net.*;

Server server;
Client client;
int Clients;
String Coord;

void setup() {
 size(600, 400);
 server = new Server(this, 12345);
}

void getCoord() {
  Coord = "";

  for (int i = 0; i < Clients ; i++) {
        String incoming = client.readStringUntil('\n');
        if (incoming != null) {
           Coord += incoming.trim() + ",";
        }
     }
}

void sendCoord() {
    println(Coord);
      server.write(Coord + "\n");
}
void draw() {
  client = server.available();
  if (client != null) {
    getCoord();
    sendCoord();
  }
}

void serverEvent(Server server, Client client) {
  String incomingMessage = "A new client has connected:" + client.ip();
  println(incomingMessage);
  Clients += 1;
}
void disconnectEvent(Client client) {
  Clients -= 1;
}
```

And here is the client code:

```
import processing.net.*;
Client client;

String Coord[] = new String[100];

void setup() {
 size(600, 400, P3D); 
 client  = new Client(this, "ENTER IP HERE FOR TESTING", 12345);
}

class Ball {
 Float X = width / 2.0;
 Float Y = height / 2.0;

 void processCoord() {
   X = parseFloat(mouseX);
   Y = parseFloat(mouseY);
 }

 void displayBall() {
  fill(0, 0, 0);

  if (Coord.length > 1) {
    if (Coord[0] != null && Coord[1] != null) {
      ellipse(parseFloat(Coord[0]), parseFloat(Coord[1]), 30, 30);
    }
  }

  if (Coord.length > 2) {
    if (Coord[2] != null && Coord[3] != null) {
      ellipse(parseFloat(Coord[2]), parseFloat(Coord[3]), 30, 30);
    }
  }
}
}

class Game {
  void mainGame() {
    background(255, 255, 255);
    imageMode(CENTER);
    ball.processCoord();
    ball.displayBall();
  }
}

Game game = new Game();
Ball ball = new Ball();

void draw() {
  game.mainGame(); 
  String XString = ball.X.toString() + ',';
  String YString = ball.Y.toString() + '\n';
  client.write(XString);
  client.write(YString);

}
void clientEvent(Client client) {
  String inComing = client.readStringUntil('\n');
  if (inComing != null) {
    inComing = inComing.substring(0, inComing.length()-1);
    Coord = inComing.split(",");
    println(Coord);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I ran your code with two clients and a server, after adding several prints, I realised that with each loop the server DOESN'T write:

x1,y1,x2,y2

which is what you want I think (x1,y1,x2,y2 being x,y coordinates of both clients).

Instead over two loops it writes:

x1,y1,x1,y1

x2,y2,x2,y2

which is to say that the coordinates of both clients are sent separately but repeated within the same inComing string through each loop.  As a result, what the clients do is, it keeps changing the location of each circle continuously.  One loop- both of them are at x1,y1. Next loop, they are both at x2,y2.  Thats why there is no flickering when they are on the same spot because then x1=x2, y1=y2.

What you need to do is find a way that the server will definitely wait before writing anything until the Coord string consists of x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3 etc etc with each loop rather than separate strings of repeated values.

Let me know what happens, if you can't fix it I can try to help you restructure your algorithm.

Comment: Hello Yigit Bireroglu, thanks for the helpful reply! Is the draw() loop being called once for each client or once for all clients. My goal is to add a simple if/else loop with a counter that will increment when a client sends its coordinates and send the coordinate list once all the coordinates for the clients are received. After it sends this the counter would be set to 0. However i do not believe this would work if the draw() loop is being called once for each client.

Comment: @zerotwo77 No problem! I don't think you should worry about the draw() and how it loops because clientEvent() will interfere with the draw()'s process each time it is called (sort of like a Listener). Therefore, the check you will do should be through clientEvent(). Your method sounds logical, however, it can still cause a problem if one client sends data twice as fast as the other one because in that case the counter will be incremented twice via the same particular client.  What I would advise is that you should really check if you have the coordinates from all clients.

Comment: @zerotwo77 To do so, you can edit your code to have identifiers that belong to each client which are sent preceding the coordinates: 
String toSend=ClientName+x+y
You could use of course the getIP() function to discern clients however as you will be running both clients from the same computer, it is possible that they will have the same IP.

Something else you can do is to send from server to clients as you do already but have the clients choose which coordinates belong to who.  Also, I don't think you should send data from clients to server continuously. Just do it when the mouse moves.

Comment: Yigit Bireroglu, thanks for all your help with solving this problem! Using the fixes that you suggested above i have since re-written the server and client in javascript using node.js and socket.io. This not only is faster but will also allow the server to be run by a service such as digital ocean (if i decide to publish the little game).

Comment: @zerotwo77 I am very glad I could help! If you end up publishing the game or if you need further help with the development, let me know:)